# Ignoring debugging changes in git

Tags: git

Sometimes I make changes to files to facilitate debugging, and I want to make sure I don't accidentally commit those changes.

One approach I have taken is to include a special comment like `// DEBUGGING` and a pre-commit hook that rejects attempts to commit such a comment. The problem is that requires having the hook set up in all copies of my repository, and I have to remember to add the comment and what exact form the script looks for.

There is also `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, but it only works at the file level, and sometimes I have debugging changes mixed with real to-be-committed changes.

Are there any other tools that help in this situation? I've started to imagine a setup that uses a second "temporary changes" index, such that status is calculated against that index, but commits are still made from the main index... but before I go too far with that idea I want to check if I'm duplicating any existing efforts.

Comment: are you open to IDE specific tips/answers? or looking for something purely git based?

Comment: You really should get in the habit of reviewing the code you're about to commit. Barring that, wrap your code in an `if(DEBUG_MODE) { // do something }` block and turn it on/off on an application-wide level.

Comment: What would be the problem with a `debugging`-branch?

Comment: +1 @ceejayoz : Would also recommend making a habit of frequent commits and using stashes... painful at the start, but pays off

Comment: Yes, I do review my code before committing, but that is a manual and error-prone process. That's why I'm looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: @dubes IDE-specific may be helpful, especially to other readers besides myself. Fire away.

Comment: @AndreasGnyp I have tried putting the debug changes in a separate branch, but it becomes a pain when I want to maintain those changes across multiple regular commits. All that extra branch switching and rebasing gets a little tiresome.

Comment: To Andreas' point branching is what `git` is all about. Create a branch do some work (even if it includes some debugging code), remove the debugging code when you're ready to ship, create a Pull Request, merge it...etc...

Answer (score 4):

This problem is solved by training yourself into a habit of following a certain disciplined routine when making commits. Secondly, review your commits before publishing them.

Train yourself never to use `git commit -a`.  Always use `git commit --patch` and interactively select each hunk. Learn how to to use s)plit and e)dit to do fine-grained selection of changes. Split every hunk which can be split and pay attention to each change that you approve for commit.

When you're editing the commit message, read the output of `git diff --cached` into the edit buffer, which shows just the changes you are committing. Refer to this material when writing your comment and delete it as you go. If you see any unwanted stuff in `git diff --cached`, then blank out the buffer, save and quit, to abort the commit.

Review your commit before pushing it out. If you see some accidental adds of debug prints, use `git reset --patch HEAD^` to interactively stage a set of changes which removes the unwanted changes. Then `git commit --amend` to combine these removes onto the commit. Since the working tree remains intact, those changes are once again just local modifications after this.

Do not regard commits as final deliverables. Assume that commits are work in progress and be prepared to refine them through several iterations before publishing them, during which time you split large commits into smaller ones, or squash smaller ones into larger ones, re-arrange their order, and make other changes.

Write down a pre-push checklist of things to look for in a new series of commits to be published and stick to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Putting debugging comments in the code is fruitless, as you will (no doubt) also do things like comment stuff out, insert `printf("foo is %d", foo)` or whatever without remembering to add the comment.

Therefore, you need to adapt your work flow such that you *do not commit your changes*.

Do your debugging in a state where the working copy is clean. To achieve this, either `git commit` or `git stash` the changes. When you have finished debugging, `git reset --hard` brings you back to where you started.

If you do need to commit (for instance to share your code), commit to a separate branch with `-debug` or similar in the branch name.

Another piece of good practice: Review every commit with `git show` before you push. Reading the code you are writing is valuable in itself (it's amazing how many formatting problems or thinkos you find this way). It also catches debugging being left in.